# Android: Grouping contact by using the first character of contact name

Tags: android

I want to group all contact in my app by using the first character of contact name. The result looks like deafault Contact Book in Android Phone. 
I don't know the name of API which can solve my problem.
Could you give me the name of it?

Picture figures: [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NN16NC0E2xo/UhSF8ZiVxVI/AAAAAAAAAb0/0tr8jZ82Zrk/s640/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Are you able to fetch the contacts? If so then i know a way to sort strings.

Comment: Yes, I fetch all contacts from phone and show all of them into listview. And I did it successfully. But, the contacts are not been sorted by group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the an object of `TreeSet` class to sort strings as shown below:

```
TreeSet mySet = new TreeSet();

mySet.add("java");
mySet.add("C");
mySet.add("Pascal");
mySet.add("ruby");

Log.d("TAG",mySet);//output here will be C,java,Pascal,ruby,

//Now our task is to fetch strings from the sorted strings in `mySet` object

String[] names= mySet.toArray(new String[mySet.size()]);

//Now you will have sorted names in the names[] array
```

So, as commented if you are able to fetch string/names from your contacts, then you can use the above concept by creating an object of type `TreeSet` and adding all your contacts to this object and converting it to an array of strings as shown above.

I'm sure this one definitely helps.

Comment: Thanks Zax! Your sugestion is very helpful for sorting contact. What about grouping contact by first chacracter of contact name. I need to group contact. Each of group has one Session (the name of session is the first character of contact name)??

Comment: In Java strings you have startsWith() function. Using this you can further get strings from names array that starts with some alphabet. If this helps please accept the answer.